# Object doesn't support property or method 'query' in angular

Tags: angularjs

**Factory**

```
(function () {
  angular.module("common.script").factory("expenseResource", ["$resource", expenseResource]);

  function expenseResource($resource) {

    var expenceCategory = function ($resource) {
        return $resource("api/expenceCategory/:expenceCategoryId");
    }

    return {
        expenceCategory: expenceCategory
    };
  }

})();
```

**Controller**

```
(function () {
  var app = angular.module("ExpenceManagerApp", ["ui.router", "common.script", "expenseResourceMock"]);

  app.config(["$stateProvider","$urlRouterProvider", function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
        .state("HomePage", {
            url:"/",
            templateUrl: "App/Main/homePage.html",

        })
        .state("Settings", {
            url: "/Settings",
            templateUrl: "App/Expense/settingsPage.html",

        })
     .state("expenceCategoryEdit", {
         url: "/expenceCategoryEdit",
         templateUrl: "App/Expense/editExpenseCategory.html",
         controller: "editExpenseCategoryCtrl as vm",
         resolve: {
             expenseResource: "expenseResource",
             expenseCategoryList: function (expenseResource) {
                 return expenseResource.expenceCategory.query().$promise;
             }
         }
     })
  }]);

}());
```

Comment: Can you please explain where you encounter this error.  At what point does the error get triggered?

Comment: `expenseResource.expenceCategory`, are you sure it's with a `c` where all other places it's spelled with an `s`?

Answer (score 1):

expenceCategory is a function, so use it as function:

```
expenseResource.expenceCategory().query().$promise
```

OR define expenceCategory as field:

```
return {
    expenceCategory: expenceCategory()
};
```

NB: your service creates new $resource each time it is launched. It should be just:

```
function expenseResource($resource) {
        return $resource("api/expenceCategory/:expenceCategoryId");
}
```

And in controller:

```
expenseResource.query().$promise
```